# Can I "pre-load" an image with JS to be used as a CSS background-image?

Tags: javascript, css, image

Can images be preemptively loaded into the page with javascript so that they can be used at any time as a CSS background image *without* any **request/upload delay**?

**If so, how?**

Comment: Did you search first? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=preload+images

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to use JS for this (with the downside of delaying the page load event).  Include something like this:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg.png.gif.bmp" style="display: none" />
```

This will trigger a request for the image, and add it to the local cache.  When you set the CSS background-image property, the image will already be in the local cache, eliminating the delay of another request.

Alternatively, you can accomplish the same thing without delaying the page load by creating the images in JavaScript (this solution allows for multiple images):

```
function preload(list, callback, imageCallback) {
    var at, len;
    at = len = list.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            if( imageCallback ) {
                imageCallback.call(this, this, len-at, len);
            }
            if( !--at ) {
                callback(list);
            }
        };
        img.src = list[i];
        list[i] = img;
    }
}
```

You'd call this with:

```
var list = preload(["1.png","2.png","3.png" ... ], function complete(list) {
   console.log('images all loaded!');
}, function loaded(image, index, listCount) {
   console.log('image ' + index + ' of + 'listCount + 'is loaded');
});
```

(Thanks to @rlemon for the preload code)

Comment: Does the page finish the "loading" animation before the img is fetched or after? I'd do some testing, if it's after, I'd consider using javascript or the page would take forever to "load"

Comment: @jt0dd - you can also set a background image on an element and give it a background position / display properties such that it won't render.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia - images added to the page this way will delay window.onLoad, yes

Comment: Risky, maybe two time loading the same image?

Comment: @Phaedra - no, not unless there's some headings on the response (eg pragma-directives) that tell the UA not to bother caching.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 - I'm not the downvoter, but at a guess: 1) Doing this procedurally is, if executed correctly, much more maintainable. The use case is dynamic content so we don't need to worry about relying on JS, and 2) large images added this way will delay the firing of the onload event.

Comment: And what if onload is not called cause img url does not exist? really better approach @FranciscoPresencia with some modification (not using hidden div).

Comment: @Phaedra i've been relying on img.onload for a while now and have never hit a case where it does not work for me. I think edge cases should be handled where they exist and this question is considerably vague.

Comment: Not so vague, if img url does not exist, onload will not be called, so if( !--at ) will never hit 0

Comment: "this question" was in regards to the OP, not your question (to be clear). I understand there is a case for this, I wasn't asking for that. I'm saying that (imo) this is an edge case. Generally images have urls. This isn't an all encompassing solution, but it is a solution that works for the majority of use cases. If the OP has issues with it then those can lead to other questions and further answers.

Comment: Also, you have to consider a load timeout, to handle the case that the image load takes too much time (or never reach higher browsers timeouts).

Comment: Also, considering all of the "fuss" you are putting up about this code. consider your answer to the same question also relies on onload.

Comment: @Phaedra do you mind to comment (or just edit in) any improvement on my code in my answer, please?

Comment: So taking in consideration that img url can be wrong is an edge case for you? really? in a real world app/site an image url can go wrong and you have to handle what to do with the element where background-image where supposed to be put.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that using an hidden img tag is the correct way, i'd rather use an "new Img(url)" and attaching to it an onload event where you can set the image as background-image to the element you want.

```
img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
  // set background-image
};
img.src = image_url;
```

be sure to put img.src after attaching onload, or you risk that the image is loaded before the event is attached.

Maybe a more complete base to build on:

```
function preload(list, callback, imageCallback, errorCallback) {
  if (typeof(list) === "undefined"
      || list.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  var len = list.length;
  var timers = {};
  var checkLen0 = function() {
    if (len === 0) {
      if (typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
      }
      delete(timers)
    }
  }
  var onload = function() {
    clearTimeout(timers[img]);
    if (typeof(imageCallback) === "function") {
      imageCallback.call(img);
    }
    len--;
    checkLen0();
  }
  var onerror = function() {
    clearTimeout(timers[img]);
    if (typeof(errorCallback) === "function") {
      errorCallback.call(img);
    }
    len--;
    checkLen0();
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = onload;
    timers[img] = window.setTimeout(5000, onerror);
    img.src = list[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I believe that this is a much better strategy. It allows you to use JS to programmatically tie together images that need preloading and their addition to the DOM. Adding images manually every time they're needed could become a maintenance hell quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

While SomeKittens answer is valid, it'll delay the page load as commented by Jimmy. If you are using jquery, I'd go with something like this instead to **keep your style, structure and logic separated**:

```
<style>
  .preload-img { display: none; }
</style>

...    

<div class = "preload-img">/path/to/image.jpg.png.gif.bmp</div>

...

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".preload-img").each(function(){
    preloadImage = new Image();
    preloadImage.src = $(this).html();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Of course, from there on you can optimize/change it. The advantadge of this is that **you can create the `<div>` dynamically with PHP and you can have all your javascript cached properly as a separated file**.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain how this answer is not helpful, please?

Comment: Uhm, i'm asking myself if this is not a risky buisness, cause you can overuse that approach making older browsers less responsive, also you have to hide all div content until background is loaded, and maybe this is not wanted at all (not a downvoter).

Comment: I changed that `data-src` and put it into the `<div>`, using a `.html()` in javascript instead of `attr("data-src")` to make it more responsive for older browsers. Besides, changed the `background-image` bit for a javascript load. Anything else you'd improve?

Comment: data-src is a better way for me, maybe in div element you want some content.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a caveat to SomeKittens' answer above, a particularly large background image should probably be added as a hidden background / via JavaScript after page load, as content images delay the firing of window.onload and may therefore create the perception of a slow loading page.

Given that it sounds like you're using dynamic content anyway, this may be an acceptable solution. It also allows you to do preloading programmatically as required, which may be better for maintenance.

Comment: That is why you shouldn't use onload, but DOMContentLoaded

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - I believe you'll still have the problem of the user seeing a 'loading spinner' on the browser for longer than they need to.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent framework for this job called Emerge.js
http://ilyabirman.net/projects/emerge/

Quote from project page:
Emerge.js is a framework for coordinated page loading. Normally, when a complex web page is loading, images appear in random order, causing unpleasant flashing. To replace it with nice and coordinated animations, programming is required. Emerge.js simplifies the task by removing the need to write any Javascript code. The framework uses a declarative approach, where you specify a desired behavior for each element and do not think about the implementation. Emerge.js uses jQuery.